# Access the interface workspace in Matlab (GUIDE)

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

Would it be possible to access and query values or variables in the data memory when an interface is run in matlab?

I need to access a data table that is created in the interface code.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the workspace from your GUI using the followng command `evalin`.

For example if you want to access a variable called `MyVar`, you can write :

```
MyVar = evalin( 'base', 'MyVar' );
```